# What exactly is "direct sunlight"?

Tags: refrigerator

I bought a small room fridge. According to the manual, I should keep it away from direct sunlight, as "direct sunlight may affect the acrylic coating". I placed it in a position where sunlight may reach it (since pretty much the whole room is well lit), but the windows are always fully covered by net drapery. Is this still direct sunlight, or can I leave it here without risking damage?

The picture below is the net drapery in question. It's dark outside now, though.

[image: The net drapery in question]

Comment: What's the nature of the net? Are there squares of light on the fridge, or is the light substantially attenuated? Chances are you'll see accelerated yellowing, but more slowly than with unobstructed light.

Comment: Direct light is just that if you have Windows with sheer coverings the room may well be well lit but the attenuation of the direct sunlight is achieved.

Comment: They are saying strong UV will damage the paint.